# How are banners kept upright?

Tags: commercial-operations

Banners are towed with a single line trailing from the plane.

[image: Photo of banner being towed by aircraft]

<sup>source: © Raimond Spekking / CC BY-SA 4.0 (via Wikimedia Commons)</sup>

How can they guarantee the banner is vertical and not upside down?

Comment: Some great answers at quora: https://www.quora.com/How-are-flying-banners-stabilized

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The tow line has the "Y" connection to a pipe/rod along the leading edge of the banner.  This keeps the leading edge perpendicular to the tow direction.  The bottom end of the pipe/rod is weighted so that once in the air gravity will rotate the banner to the vertical.

Answer (score 11):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_advertising#Fixed-wing_aircraft):

> There usually are three lines to the actual towing line. The top one
>   is shortest so that the center of gravity will be below the center of
>   the boom. This to ensure that the message will hang vertical. In
>   addition, often the bottom will be fitted with a weight.